# How to sum numbers in an array

Tags: ruby

I am trying to sum the numbers in an array with a function:

```
def total(numbers)
 numbers.each do |e|
  total_number = e + total_number
  return total_number
 end
end

puts total([1,2,3,4])
```

But I keep getting an error message saying:

> nil can't be coerced into Fixnum (repl):18:in '+'

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

The each > do loop works outside of a function.

Comment: `total_number` is initially `nil`, so you have `total_number = e + nil`. And you probably want to return after the loop, not within it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not initialized the `total_number` variable, so it is giving that error, try this

```
def total(numbers)
 total_number = 0
 numbers.each do |e|
  total_number += e # Same as your total_number = e + total_number
 end
 return total_number
end

puts total([1,2,3,4])
```

But the best way would be to use the ruby inbuilt method of array.

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
total_number = array.inject(:+)
```

Comment: Another thing that was initially wrong, but has been fixed in this answer is the location of the return statement. It was in the loop, so the function returned on the first iteration, yielding only the first number of the array.

Comment: `return` not needed here

Comment: This would fix this, although I'd say @AlexGolubenko has the proper approaches for doing this. No need to reinvent the wheel, however minor the method might be.

Answer (score 7):

There are many different ways to do it:

```
numbers.sum

numbers.inject(:+)
```

And many others. Don't be shy to check [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/) next time ;)

Comment: @Stefan sure, I was late with editing while I was thinking about a possible variant of method refactoring)

Comment: Maybe you could show how to refactor the OP's method from `each` with external counter to `inject` with a block to `inject` with just `:+` to `sum`.